# styling a table header with a border box

Tags: html, css

this is the style I want for my table

[image: Table]

The header row got a border at the bottom. And this is my table

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the horizontal line is dashed. How can I get a full line? I tried styling the header table row like

```css
#header{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="header">
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your CSS so it looks like this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-spacing: 0
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The added part is `border-spacing`.